# ios 7 label settext issue

Tags: label, ios7, stringwithformat

help me Please understand one strange thing...why the label text wraps to the next line while using stringWithFormat: and it does not appear in the same.How to set it in one line?
PS: in iOS6 all was fine...but in iOS7 it has broken dawn (

```
[lbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                                        SomeText,secondPartOfText
                                        ]];
```

---

*label in iOS 7*
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII

SomeText:
 secondPartOfText

IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII

*label in iOS 6*
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII

SomeText:secondPartOfText

IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII

Comment: I don't know why but in the line which I take from the file the symbol "\r" appeared...there wasn't this symbol in iOS6 , but in iOS7 it appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't even compile, to set two lines text in your UILabel you shall do it like this:

```
[lbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:\n%@",
                                        SomeText,secondPartOfText
                                        ]];
```

also you need to set number of line to 2 for your label:

```
lbl.numberOfLines = 2;
```

This will work for iOS6 and iOS7, and to set it in one line:

```
[lbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@",
                                        SomeText,secondPartOfText
                                        ]];
```

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake writing a question (the question was corrected) , the thing is not in colon...it shouldn't be there) I tried to use 'lbl.numberOfLines' and '[lbl sizeToFit]' but it didn't help...